# checkbox of popup window getting reflected in parent window

Tags: javascript, html

I have a popup window with checkboxes.when i select a checkbox i need that checkbox itself(not the value associated with the check box) to be reflected in my parent window,,its kind of copying checkbox and pasting it in my parent window.Is there anyway to accomplish this in javascript ?
Thanks in advance for ur valuable suggetions

Answer (score 1):

you can pass object to the parent window..  like this
on child window 
`function SetCheckBox()
{
var chbox = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
window.opener.GetCheckBox(chbox);
}`

on parent window 
`function GetCheckBox(obj) {
 var chkbox = obj;
 //now do what ever you want . you got your child checkbox object to parent 
}`

Comment: Hey thank u Ujjwal I kind of understood ur script,,can u pls guide me in depth coz am a beginner in javascript.Hope am not asking for too much.Thanks